# shortcode appears on the top of the content

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I create a shortcode but for some reason it appears above the main content, just before the page content start.

```
function aran_show_expertises(  ) {

$expertises = new WP_Query( 'post_type=aran_expertises' );

// The loop:
if( $expertises -> have_posts() ):
    while( $expertises -> have_posts() ): $expertises -> the_post();
        $slider =
            "<script type='text/javascript'>
                jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                   $(window).load(function() {
                      $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                        animation: 'slide',
                        animationLoop: false,
                        itemWidth: 210,
                        itemMargin: 5
                      });
                  });
                });
            </script>

            <div class='flexslider'>
              <ul class='slides'>
                <li>
                  <span> " . the_title() . "</span>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>";


    endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();

else:

    $slider = "no posts";

endif;

return $slider;
}
add_shortcode( 'expertises_slider', 'aran_show_expertises' );
```

One weird thing - when the if statement returns false, it doesn't happen.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: That doesn't look like valid PHP. Doesn't it produce any error messages?

Comment: nope it works fine..

Comment: O wow. I go away for a couple of years, and all languages start to borrow elements from one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mange to solve this by changing `the_title()` to `get_the_title()`, the problem occurs because I output the title instead of return it.